# When a non-vectored interrupt occurs,does the processor ever look up the vector table?

Tags: cpu, interrupts

When a *non-vectored* interrupt occurs,does the processor ever look up the *vector table* ?

Talking of 8085 , is it different ?

Answer (score 1):

An interrupt address table (otherwise known as "interrupt vector table") allows for the
interrupt service routine's location to be changed by *software*.  This only requires the interrupting device to send the ID of the interrupt, which is then used as the offset in the interrupt address table to determine where to relocate the program counter/instruction
pointer.  This only applies to a vectored interrupt.

Conversely, in a non-vectored interrupt, the peripheral itself provides the address of the interrupt service
routine directly to the processor. This requires more time for an interrupt to be serviced, since the address must be retrieved from the interrupting device every time the
interrupt is triggered.

Comment: so does it need to look the vector table ?

Comment: @steve no, the device itself supplies the address of the subroutine.  In a vectored interrupt, the processor already knows the address (since it's in the table).

Comment: @Breakthrough can you please answer following question. I myself have attempted but I am not very much confident in my reasoning so I want to confirm that and more importantly, my fellow students have different opinions on the same. So here is a question -

Comment: Non vectored interrupt in a system is used for - A: Informing power failure, B: Changing program execution, C: Connecting more number of IO devices, D: Connecting only one device.

Comment: I think D is more appropriate as in that case we don't need vector-interrupt as whenever an interrupt occurs we surely know which IS to execute.

Comment: A is not the right one as there may be other devices in the system so we would prefer vector-interrupt over non-vectored-interrupt.